# How to call this cURL from Windows forms application?

Tags: c#, curl, httpclient

I am using WRIKE PM on my application, and I'm rely on their APIs. I was using V2 which has no issues, they've updated their API to V3, and I am supposed to update my application.

On version 2, I'll use this URL to get time logs,

```
https://www.wrike.com/api/json/v2/wrike.timelog.filter?fromDate=2014-02-20&toDate=2014-05-16
```

I'll change parameters, `fromDate` and `toDate` to get details.

On version 3, they have changed their URL to

```
https://www.wrike.com/api/v3/timelogs?createdDate={"start":"2015-08-10T14:59:35Z"}&trackedDate={"equal":"2015-08-11"}
```

Wrike Link: https://developers.wrike.com/documentation/api/methods/query-timelogs

Please help me how can I create a method to call this cURL and get my details?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at using [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/). While you could build some classes and then use [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) to serialize them, just build up your query string and pass it to RestSharp. RestSharp will do the equivalent to Curl.

Or if you desperately want to use CURL then Google "curl c# wrapper"